# I want to loop through a referenced schema with array elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I want to loop through a referenced schema with array elements, yet there is something printed called `*ref`, if so what is this and does it mean anything ?

```
<ref *1> [
  EmbeddedDocument {
    __parentArray: [Circular *1],
    __index: 0,
    '$__parent': model { '$__': [InternalCache], '$isNew': false, _doc: [Object] },
    '$__': InternalCache { activePaths: [StateMachine] },
    _doc: {
      label: 'Link',
      link: 'https://www.link.com/sr?rb=1617',
      links: [Array],
      _id: [ObjectId]
    },
    '$isNew': false,
    [Symbol(mongoose#documentArrayParent)]: model { '$__': [InternalCache], '$isNew': false, _doc: [Object] }
  }
]
[
  {
    label: 'Link',
    link: 'https://www.mylink.com/sr?rb=1617',
    links: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      ... 2752 more items
    ],
    _id: new ObjectId('65c92d92d0a329e4c356d99c')
  }
]
```

my purpose is to print just the array below yes it adds something as `<ref *1> EmbeddedDocument`

the document's name let's say is `user.correspondingLinks`,

so i have to put `user.correspondingLinks[0]` with the index `0`, but what about the `<*ref>` if i pass along with ejs to the html page, i dont get the ref anymore, this only prints on the main module, i think....

So how to get rid of this `<*ref>` while printing

**EDIT**

```
// USER SCHEMA MODEL FOR MONGODB //

const categoryLinkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  label: String,
  link: String,
  links: { type: Array, default: [] }
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true
   },
  password: String,
  email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true
   },
  categoryLinks: {
    type: [categoryLinkSchema],
    validate: [function(doc) {
        for(let d of doc){
            const duplicates = this.categoryLinks.filter(function(c){
                return c.link === d.link || c.label === d.label;
            })
            if(duplicates.length > 1){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }, 'Each categoryLinks.label must be unique.']
  },
  links : { type : Array , "default" : [] },
  imagelink: String,
  plan: String,
  bakiye: Number,
  phoneNumber: Number
});
```

and i use thi `app.post` to handle my request

```
app.get('/cats/:kategorilabel', function(req, res) {

  if(!req.session.username) { return res.redirect('/login') };

  userModel.findOne({
    username: req.session.username
  }).then(
    (user) => {
      console.dir(user.categoryLinks) // this is where I get the log with *ref, 
     //locals.labelLinks.find(element => element.label == locals.katlabel) this is the find i do with ejs on browser, yet it is slower due to data transfer
      res.render('labelkategori', {labelLinks: user.categoryLinks, katlabel: req.params['kategorilabel']}); 
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      console.log('Error: ' + error.code + " error: " + error);
    }
  );
})
```

so the `user.categoryLinks` is a big object, i just want to find the corresponding label and send response, otherwise it becomes slow. and the `*ref` messes the structure, so i have to send the whole object to the client browser and find on html, which is way slower

Comment: This is a circular structure. Ref tells you that this object is used somewhere deeper, specifically where `Circular *1` is shown. I'm pretty sure that all of these meta data is skipped when passed to ejs

Comment: is it also possible to use the data WITHOUT the meta data on the main module. because when i use ```typeof``` it returns ```object``` but is supposed to return an ```Array```. So is it possible to use the array without the complex metada and mess up the indices ?

Comment: Can you post the code where you get this data object and how you are logging it to the console. There may be a step you are missing.

Comment: pasted whole code

Comment: so i have an array of objects but i want to find a key value 'label' and send it as a response. if i send the whole array as response the page's loading speed becomes slow, so i want to filter but i get the *res so i cant parse it as an array @jQueeny

Comment: Just seen this. You can filter the array before sending it to your view. I will write a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query your data just pass in the criteria for matching the properties of the array element you want to output.

For example, if you only want `categoryLinks.label` equal to `bim-bebek` you can add that into the query object. When mongoose makes a match you can tell it to only output the `categoryLinks` array element using the `$` positional operator in the projection object. However, you will also have to specify all of the other fields you want to output if you need them like so:

```js
userModel.findOne(
   {
      username: req.session.username,
      "categoryLinks.label": "bim-bebek"
   },
   {
      "categoryLinks.$": 1
      // username: 1,  //< Include other fields in your projection if you need them
      // email: 1,
   }
).then(user => {
   res.render('labelkategori', {
      labelLinks: user.categoryLinks, 
      katlabel: req.params['kategorilabel']
   });
}).catch(error =>{
   console.log('Error: ' + error.code + " error: " + error);
   res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Error on server'
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since ```categoryLinks.label``` is unique, using ```$``` for projection doesn't change anything right, it only makes it better for iteration since it stops looping the array the moment it finds with ```$``` ? thank you in advance!

Comment: @unbaym that's correct. The projection stage just acts as a filter on what fields are output in your query. The source data in your collection at rest is unchanged.

Comment: ```Error: 31249 error: MongoServerError: Path collision ``` for only projecting label for example, do i need to do 

```{"categoryLinks.$": 1, "categoryLinks.label" : 1 }```

Comment: When you project `"categoryLinks.$": 1` you are outputting the full object from the `categoryLinks` array that met the matching criteria from `"categoryLinks.label": "bim-bebek`. However if you only want to output the `label` from that matching object you will need to do `"categoryLinks.$.label": 1` instead.

Comment: thank you very much... lastly, you know I have links which I parse data with... I used ```workerThreads``` for each request because Promises were synchronous and causing the whole program to freeze. and I used cheerio to parse the html. YET it is soooo slow. I don't know what to do. Can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78010893/cheerio-is-so-slow-inside-a-for-loop-makes-requests-wait-in-between , maybe you have some ideas

Comment: I can have a look.

Comment: Hi yes I got your email. Best not to put your phone number on here for your security. Stack Overflow has chat rooms https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms

Comment: even though headless selenium/puppeteer would be my less preferred, since i might be looping through 10s of thousands of links, that is a lot of... memory or tabs

Comment: i think I found something ```JSDOM``` is way faster than this... but again it seems to be synchronous so each request is processed 1 by 1. Maybe i should use worker threads for this then... (to complete the operation faster) 

or async functions, do they also work ?

Comment: If you're doing testing then I think puppeteer would be a good option.

Comment: no it is not testing, it is real app running... so i might be scanning 10s of thousands of links in loop with intervals... is why i wanted to avoid puppeteer. <a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom">JSDOM </a>seems to be working fast indeed, but since it is synchronous(only processing 1 body at a time) it still waits a bit. To make all the request process it at the same time, i can either use workerthreads... or something like async functions work ? Aren't async functions meant for this already? if i could explain my problem

Comment: I don't have much experience in that domain unfortunately.